# How to prevent uitextfield from expanding it's width but allow its height with text?

Tags: ios, swift, textfield

Alright, so Ive created a uitextfield programmatically here -

```
ideaTextField.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenSize.width * (0.72), screenSize.height * (120/568)) //limit on characters
        ideaTextField.text = "Give us an idea"
        ideaTextField.center = CGPointMake(screenSize.width * 0.5, screenSize.height * 1.1)
        ideaTextField.font = UIFont(name: "Roboto", size: screenSize.height * (16/568))
        ideaTextField.textAlignment = .Center
        ideaTextField.textColor = colorWithHexString(chosenColor)

        ideaTextField.delegate = self
        ideaTextField.addTarget(self, action: "startedEntering2:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchDown)
        view.addSubview(ideaTextField)
```

and as you can see I've explicitly set the width/frame and tried but cant like a label set the number of lines to 0/infinity. My problem is that when I start entering text beyond the width of the field the field just keeps expanding horizontally :

[image]

Im setting a word count limit but if anything, I need the field to ONLY expand vertically. How can I do this?

Comment: `UITextField` is for a single line of text. You need to use `UITextView` for multiple lines. `UITextView` will drop down to the next line automatically.

Comment: **1.** Use textview,make its scrolling disabled **2.** Add constraint Leading,Trailing,Top and Bottom. **3.** Change Bottom layout  relation from **Equal** to **Greater than or equal**

Answer (score 0):

Using constraints would likely solve this problem. If you were to adjust the horizontal hugging and stretching values by, say 1, then I believe that it should do the trick. If you need a refresher on how to make constraints programmatically I have attached a link:

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html

Cheers!